# Is it possible to define lifecycle methods in Vue 3 while using the <script setup> syntax?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-sfc

I have defined a SFC similar to the one below

```
<script setup>
const msg = 'Hello World!'
const props = defineProps({....})
.....
function onMounted() {
    console.log('the component is now mounted')
}
</script>

<template>
    <p>{{ msg }}</p>
</template>
```

The `onMounted` function is not executing at all.

I wasn't able to find anything in the Vue documentation. Is it even possible to declare lifecycle hooks like this?

Comment: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SFC with the setup script is using the CompositionAPI, so you also have to define the livecycle hooks the same way:

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
onMounted(() => {
    console.log('mounted!')
})
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#lifecycle-hooks